# Android Augmented Reality Pro AR 9: activity gets back when displays too many markers

Tags: android, augmented-reality

I'm using this very useful tutorial (https://github.com/RaghavSood/ProAndroidAugmentedReality) for developing a custom AR app.
It works pretty fine, but when I display markers extracted from a file folder (sometimes) the app gets blocked and restarts from the previous activity.
I suppose it's because of the big number of markers situated in the same point of the screen.
Infact, when I lower the radius, and then showing a littler number of markers, the activity continues to work.
Besides, I've tried to modify the function "getTextWidth()" as many people suggest on the net.
I don't know how to reduce the number of Markers drawn on the same point of the screen (so indipendently from reducing the radius). Can you suggest me something?  THANKS A LOT!!!!!

I show you the LocalDataSource.java modified:

```
package com.example.pointofinterests;

import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.pointofinterests.R;
import com.example.pointofinterests.IconMarker;
import com.example.pointofinterests.Marker;

/**
* This class should be used as a example local data source. It is an example of
* how to add data programatically. You can add data either programatically,
* SQLite or through any other source.
* 
* @author Justin Wetherell <phishman3579@gmail.com>
*/
public class LocalDataSource extends DataSource {

    private List<Marker> cachedMarkers = new ArrayList<Marker>();
    private static Bitmap icon = null;

    public LocalDataSource(Resources res) {
        if (res == null) throw new NullPointerException();
            createIcon(res);
    }

    protected void createIcon(Resources res) {
       if (res == null) throw new NullPointerException();
           icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(res, R.drawable.icon);
    }

    public List<Marker> getMarkers() {
        try{
        String TestoIDPercorsi = readFileAsString("/sdcard/Epulia/IDPercorsi.txt");
        if(TestoIDPercorsi==""){
           // DOING NOTHING
        }else {
            String[] IDPercorso = TestoIDPercorsi.split("#");
            for(int l=0; l<IDPercorso.length-1; l++){
                String TestoPercorso = readFileAsString("/sdcard/Epulia/Percorso" +          IDPercorso[l] + ".txt");
                if (TestoPercorso.equals("")){
                }else {
                    ArrayList<String> IDSTEPS2 = new ArrayList<String>();
                    String[] temp = TestoPercorso.split("#");
                    for (int j=1; j < temp.length; j++){
                        Log.d("RIGA_" + j + "_" + IDPercorso[l], temp[j]);
                        if(temp[j].substring(0,2).contains("P")){//POI
                            String[] POI = temp[j].split("\\|");
                            String id = POI[1];
                            String description = POI[2];
                            Double lat = Double.parseDouble(POI[3]);
                            Double lng = Double.parseDouble(POI[4]);
                            String type = POI[5];

                            Marker poi = new IconMarker(description, lat,lng, 0, Color.DKGRAY, icon);
                            cachedMarkers.add(poi);

                        }
                    }



                }
            }


        }
    }catch (Exception e){
        Log.e("EXCEPTION", "> " + e);
    }



    return cachedMarkers;
}

public static String readFileAsString(String filePath) {

    String result = "";
    File file = new File(filePath);
    if ( file.exists() ) {
       FileInputStream fis = null;
        try {
           fis = new FileInputStream(file);
            char current;
            while (fis.available() > 0) {
                current = (char) fis.read();
                result = result + String.valueOf(current);

            }

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("TourGuide", e.toString());
        } finally {
            if (fis != null)
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException ignored) {
            }
        }

   }
    return result;
    }



}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to thank the Author of the Tutorial who helped me in fixing the problem.
I report his answer that soled my problem:

Not sure why you have that limitation but this should limit the number of Markers drawn on the screen.

In class AugmentedView.java

You can introduce a new member variable:

```
private static int MAX_NUM_TO_DRAW = 10;
```

Then in the method onDraw(Canvas canvas):

You can quit the drawing loop early.

```
        int i=0;
        ListIterator<Marker> iter = collection.listIterator(collection.size());
        while (iter.hasPrevious() && i<MAX_NUM_TO_DRAW ) {
            Marker marker = iter.previous();
            marker.draw(canvas);
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: I have filled cachedMarkers list of LocalDataSource class with the IconMarker of current lat long. But still i can't able to see any sort of markers over Camera SurfaceView. Can you tell me where i am doing incorrect? Since i have added only one-two marker location so the larger marker wont be a issue in my case. But still i updated my AugmentedView class with what you have suggested

Comment: into getMarkers() I've done: Marker poi = new IconMarker(id, description, lat,lng, 0, Color.DKGRAY, icon);           cachedMarkers.add(poi);